# Displaying contents of a knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Hi guys I'm new to java Script knockout framework, I would like to display contents of an array using knockout, in reality I want to retrieve these contents from a database using ajax but I decided to start with something simpler, which is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      function requestViewModel() {

          this.branchName = ko.observable();
          this.allItems = ko.observableArray({items:[{orderItemId:1,
                description:"Chocolate",
                unitCost:8.50,
                quantity:10,
                total:84.0},
                {orderItemId:2,
                description:"Milk",
                unitCost:5.0,
                quantity:10,
                total:50.0},
                {orderItemId:3,
                description:"Sugar",
                unitCost:10.0,
                quantity:20,
                total:200.0}]});

          };

      ko.applyBindings(new requestViewModel()); 

});
```

......and here is my HTML

```
 Branch Name:   <input type="text" name = "branchName">

<br><br><br><br>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Item id</th><th>Description</th><th>Unit Cost</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: orderItemId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: unitCost"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: quantity"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help where you can coz I get an error which is:

"Error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined."

Comment: If you are using Chrome for development, you can use the incredibly handy Knockout Context extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. You need to pass in an array instead of an object like so:

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([{orderItemId:1,
            description:"Chocolate",
            unitCost:8.50,
            quantity:10,
            total:84.0},
            {orderItemId:2,
            description:"Milk",
            unitCost:5.0,
            quantity:10,
            total:50.0},
            {orderItemId:3,
            description:"Sugar",
            unitCost:10.0,
            quantity:20,
            total:200.0}]);
```

Note the removal of `{items:` and `}`.

Comment: Thanks jeremy... I'm lazy huh...!